# CI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: open /dev/pts/0: operation not permitted: unknown

Tags: docker

When i run the below command

```
$ docker-compose exec web bash
```

This is the error which i faced :

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: open /dev/pts/0: operation not permitted: unknown

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: just I deleted all containers and build

Answer (score 9):

This happened to me too.
But I accidentally stopped the container and after restarting the container, the problem was solved.

This way worked for all my containers.

[image]

Comment: restarting the container allowed me to open an interactive shell. 

Answer (score 1):

this may happen on a `selinux` enabled kernel - caused by an [upstream issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/43969) of the `runc` component.

a [interim workaround](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/43969#issuecomment-1217629129) may help until the issue is resolved.

Comment: Answers that are just links tend to get deleted.  Can you [edit] the answer to include a description of what needs to be done?

Comment: the issue has been resolved via https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/44037

Answer (score 0):

Is a problem with iptables. If you are using a firewall like shorewall or selinux and modify any rules or policies, this will happen. SOlution is to restart docker engine or restart the container itself so the rules can be generated again.