# OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: open /dev/pts/0: operation not permitted: unknown

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd, runc, kubernetes-rook

I have read many links similar to my issue, but none of them were helping me to resolve the issue.

**Similar Links**:

1. [Failed to exec into the container due to permission issue after executing 'systemctl daemon-reload'](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/7219)
2. [OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: open /dev/pts/0: operation not permitted: unknown](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/issues/3551)
3. [CI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: open /dev/pts/0: operation not permitted: unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73379718/ci-runtime-exec-failed-exec-failed-unable-to-start-container-process-open-de)
4. [OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: open /dev/pts/0: operation not permitted: unknown](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/43969)
5. [Fail to execute docker exec](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=277995)
6. [OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "open /proc/self/fd: no such file or directory": unknown](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/246)

**Problem Description**:

I have created a new Kubernetes cluster using `Kubespray`. When I wanted to execute some commands in one of containers I faced to the following error:

###### Executed Command

```bash
kubectl exec -it -n rook-ceph rook-ceph-tools-68d847b88d-7kw2v -- sh
```

###### Error:

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: open /dev/pts/1: operation not permitted: unknown
> command terminated with exit code 126

I have also logged in to the node, which runs the pod, and try executing the container using `docker exec` command, but the error was not changed.

**Workarounds**:

- As I have found, the error code (126) implies that the permissions are insufficient, but I haven't faced this kind of error (like executing `sh`) in Docker or Kubernetes.
- I have also checked whether `SELinux` is enabled or not (as it has been said in the 3rd link).

  ```bash
  apt install policycoreutils
  sestatus
  # Output
  SELinux status:                 disabled
  ```
- In the 5th link, it was said to check whether you have updated the kernel, and I didn't upgrade anything on the nodes.

  ```bash
  id; stat /dev/pts/0
  # output
  uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
    File: /dev/pts/0
    Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   character special file
  Device: 18h/24d Inode: 3           Links: 1     Device type: 88,0
  Access: (0600/crw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    5/     tty)
  Access: 2022-08-21 12:01:25.409456443 +0000
  Modify: 2022-08-21 12:01:25.409456443 +0000
  Change: 2022-08-21 11:54:47.474457646 +0000
   Birth: -
  ```
- Also tried `/bin/sh` instead of `sh` or `/bin/bash`, but not worked and the same error occurred.

Can anyone help me to find the root cause of this problem and then solve it?

Comment: ```kubectl run debug --image=alpine -i --tty -- sh``` can you check if this command work

Comment: @Adiii It works, but it doesn't work for executing the existing pods like `rook-ceph-tools-68d847b88d-7kw2v`, I've mentioned it here.

Comment: is there any volume mount? is the image support your platform? `k describe node node_name | grep "kubernetes.io/arch"`

Comment: `docker inspect  image my-image | grep Architecture` the node and image architecture should match, if not then you need to rebuild image

Comment: `docker build --platform linux/x86-64 -t demo-image .` or `platform linux/amd64`

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]; what is the application code required to reproduce the issue?  Do you think this is a duplicate of the [existing question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73379718/ci-runtime-exec-failed-exec-failed-unable-to-start-container-process-open-de)?  Or do you think this is about the way you installed the cluster (in which case another site like [sf] may be more appropriate)?

Comment: @Adiii Yes! they are the same and the architecture is `amd64`.

Comment: @DavidMaze No it is not depend on the way I have installed the cluster. I was just for describing what has happened to me. No, it's not the duplicate question, since non of them work properly and the problem is still unresolved.

Comment: Try `kubectl exec -i -n rook-ceph rook-ceph-tools-68d847b88d-7kw2v -- sh` without the -t. You might get a running shell without tty. Just test at empty prompt. E.g. `date` and `exit`.
If it works, you have hit a bug in runc and have to update to v1.1.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue may relate to docker, first drain your node.

```
kubectl drain <node-name>
```

Second, SSH to the node and restart docker service.

```
systemctl restart docker.service
```

At the end try to execute your command.

Comment: If you are using Docker Compose, bringing your containers down and back up again also solves the problem.  My question is what might be causing Docker to do this?

Comment: @Erich I'm not sure this is exactly Docker related, but this solution fix his problem.

Comment: looks like this was a bug in `runc` 1.1.3 that has since been fixed.  i upgraded containerd on my machine and haven't seen this issue since. https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/pull/3554

Comment: @Erich Definitely not just docker. I'm getting this with Podman under runc. I'm on Almalinux 8 which has runc 1.1.3. Hopefully runc 1.1.4 shows up soon. I thought this was some bug in Cockpit's Podman plugin, but guess not....